# Python dictionary format change splitting keys

Tags: python, dictionary, format

How could i go from this format of dictionary

```
{'A.B': 7, 'C.D': 5, 'A.D': 34}
```

to this:

```
{'A': {'B':7, D:34} , 'C': {'D': 5} }
```

Meaning of key 'A.B' is that i go from A to B and its value means 7 times, so what i am trying to do is change this format so that my dictionary key is where i go from and its value its a dictionary with his destinations (one or more) and the times of each.

I have tried several things, but for now things are not working out.

I have tried using for with a new dictionary but it overrides my keys.

Comment: Will the depth of the keys always be 2 or is a key like `A.B.C` possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick approach:

```
d = {'A.B': 7, 'C.D': 5, 'A.D': 34}

dicts_init = {key.split('.')[0]: {} for key, value in d.items()}
for key, value in d.items():
    root_k, val = key.split(".")
    dicts_init[root_k][val] = value
print(dicts_init)
```

Outputs:

```
{'A': {'B': 7, 'D': 34}, 'C': {'D': 5}}
```

Comment: and how would you insert data here {'A': {}, 'B': {} } using for without overriding, just adding more to the key like a list, for example {'A': {'C':1,'D':4}, 'B': {} }

Comment: Not sure what you mean. but just:
```dicts_init[root_k][val] = value``` 
You can't use same key in dict.

Answer (score 2):

Using defaultdict:

```py
d = {'A.B': 7, 'C.D': 5, 'A.D': 34}

from collections import defaultdict

formatted_d = defaultdict(dict)
for k, v in d.items():
    top_key, bottom_key = k.split('.')
    formatted_d[top_key][bottom_key] = v
```

Without defaultdict:

```py
formatted_d = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    top_key, bottom_key = k.split('.')
    if top_key not in formatted_d:
        formatted_d[top_key] = {}
    formatted_d[top_key][bottom_key] = v
```

Comment: Ah, same idea, just some minutes earlier - +1.

Answer (score 2):

Clean and easy to understand with `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dct = {'A.B': 7, 'C.D': 5, 'A.D': 34}

new_dict = defaultdict(dict)

for key, value in dct.items():
    root, descendant = key.split(".")
    new_dict[root][descendant] = value

print(new_dict)
```

This yields

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'A': {'B': 7, 'D': 34}, 'C': {'D': 5}})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {'A.B': 7, 'C.D': 5, 'A.D': 34}
result = {}

for key in d:
    current, destination = key.split('.')
    times = d.get(key)
    if current not in result.keys():
        result[current] = {destination: int(times)}
    else:
        result[current][destination] = int(times)

print(result)
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `input` as a variable name. It is the name of a built-in function: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input